# Weird edges in car roof

Tags: modeling

I was making low-poly Audi A6 C6 avant. So i made almost everything but I have a problem. When I try to make the last wall of the roof, a problem arises. One of the edges spoils the whole look. I use the Subdivision Surface but even when it turns it off, the error still shows up. Please help[image]

[image]

It's not even helping when using "Shade Flat". And yes, I enabled AutoSmooth to 30*

Comment: Could you post an image of your object in edit mode without the SS modifier so we can see the topology? It's likely just a duped or unmerged edge or possibly a slight upward "kink" in the mesh surface. Either way, its hard to tell without seeing the edge lines.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/JLBrYiH.png here you are

Comment: Still nothing. When I'm trying to fill the empty face it creates a weird edge, that is sharp... Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Yeah, not sure then. have you tried removing all dupes (Select all in edit mode, then `mesh > Clean up > Merge by distance`) and making sure the normals are all facing the right way (`mesh > normals > recalculate outside`)?

Comment: Yeah, thank you :DDDDD Some faces were inverted, so it was looking weird. Once again, thank you :)